# how to check the username and password

Tags: asp.net

I want to built a web application so first there is a problem of login control.
I made a connection to the database using sql datasource connection control. While testing it shows result,
but while browsing it, an error occured. There must be a code to check the username and password to authenticate the user. Can someone write me that code and tell me where is my error?

Comment: Can you provide some code for everybody to look at?  We can't answer your question without knowing what you are currently doing.

Answer (score -1):

```
// pseudocode
String username = req.POST["username"];
String password = req.POST["password"];
boolean exists = SQLObject.query("select * from user where username=${username} and password=${password}");
```

Comment: Next time, don't use the ` and ` for multiple lines of code but use a code block ;)

Comment: You shouldn't run SQL code based on end-user input without any checks. See this article on SQL injection attacks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: i think if people asking simple questions about how to compare username and password, he doesnt want to involve complexity like sql injection?

Comment: But you also do not have all of the information to provide a solution. This is more hazardous than helpful without knowing what is truly going on (platform, language--the real problem not clearly stated in this question).

Comment: yea do not want complexity just answer in simple way

Comment: @Inspiron - you have not given enough information for us to answer anything safely. Please read my comment on your question.